# “Man is created only to have pleasure from Hashem etc.” - How does the Mesilas Yeshorim know this?

Tags: mesilas-yesharim

The [Mesilas Yeshorim says in Perek 2](http://www.sefaria.org/Messilat_Yesharim.2.2?lang=bi&with=Sheets&lang2=bi),

> והנה מה שהורונו חכמינו זכרונם לברכה הוא, שהאדם לא נברא אלא להתענג על
>   ה' ולהנות מזיו שכינתו
>
> And this is what our Rabbis of blessed memory
>   have taught us, that man is created only to have pleasure from Hashem
>   and to enjoy the brightness of his Presence.

Where do our Rabbis teach this?

Comment: There are three basic views regarding the motivation of Creation: 
1) HaShem created the world for His Glory (per [*Avos* 6:12](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%90%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%95_%D7%99%D7%90), [*Y'sha'ya* 43:7](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt1043.htm#7), and the *sheva b'rachos* blessing "*shehakol bara lichvodo*" in [*K'subos* 8a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=15&daf=8&format=text)). This seems to be Rashi's view ([Commentary on *Mishlei* 16:4](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%22%D7%92_%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%99_%D7%98%D7%96_%D7%93)).

Comment: 2) HaShem created the world for the sake of bestowing goodness. This appears to be the view of the Ramchal, and it is a common view among later kabbalists and *sifrei chassidus*. This view may be supported by verses such as [*T'hillim* 89:3](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2689.htm#3) ("עוֹלָם חֶסֶד יִבָּנֶה").

Comment: 3) R' Chaim Brisker said the world was created because of HaShem's inscrutable will. R' Yosef Dov Soloveitchik [added](http://www.bcbm.org/shiurim/rav-soloveitchik/gemarahalacha/mishnayos_end_of_sota_chevlei_moshiach_brisker_stories_yartzeit_rabanit_1973_r/): "The will of the Holy One Blessed be He does not need an extraneous goal; the goal is the realization of the will of Holy One Blessed be He itself." This view is supported by [*B'rachos* 33b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=33b&format=text) ("וחד אמר מפני שעושה מדותיו של הקדוש ברוך הוא רחמים ואינן אלא גזרות")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He continues there

> This is what our sages of blessed memory said "today to do them, and
>   tomorrow to receive their reward" (Eruvin 22:1)... When you look
>   further into the matter, you will see that true perfection lies only
>   in clinging to G-d. This is what King David said "But as for me,
>   closeness to G-d is my good" (Ps.73:28).. For only this is the good,
>   while anything besides this that people consider good is really
>   emptiness and mistaken worthlessness

Rabbi Yosef Spinner in his commentary there says:

> "true perfection (shelemus) is only clinging (deveikus) to G-d.." - it
>   should be noted that the author started with perfection (shelemus) and
>   continued with "clinging" (devekus). According to his words in various
>   places, the explanation is that perfection (shelemus), clinging
>   (deveikus), and the "true good" - all are basically the same matter.
>   Namely, G-d is the "true good", which is the matter of His perfection.
>   He wants to bestow this good and perfection to His creations (human
>   beings). However to receive this good and perfection is only possible
>   in a situation of "clinging". Hence, when he says the true perfection
>   is only clinging to G-d, his intent is that through clinging to G-d it
>   is possible to attain perfection and [true] good..
>   from [here](http://dafyomireview.com/mesilat.php?d=3e=3)

See also Derech Hashem 2:1 "God alone is the true good and therefore His beneficent desire would not be satisfied unless it could bestow that very good.."

Comment: What a great resource! Thank you. This moves the question on to "He wants to bestow this good and perfection to His creations (human beings)." I have encountered this idea before but would still like to know what the source of that idea is so as to to complete the point.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok you mean why God wants to bestow good?

Comment: Yes please .............

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok because this is the true good/perfection. see derech Hashem 2:1 "God alone is the true good and therefore His beneficent desire would not be satisfied unless it could bestow that very good.."

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok found some more sources; Klach Pitchei Chachma #3 "all good desires to bestow good..". also Daat Tevunot siman 18

Answer (score 0):

Formally the MY itself explain the source of this statement "והוא מה שאמרו זכרונם לברכה". But even if the structure is apparent and the content is hard to understand.

Lets try to discover the reasoning the MY.
The first assertion is that Man is created to have pleasure with Hashem.
The second assertion is that this will append in Olam Haba.

The proof is found by the author in a mishna in Avot (4, 16).

> רַבִּי יַעֲקֹב אוֹמֵר, הָעוֹלָם הַזֶּה דּוֹמֶה לִפְרוֹזְדוֹר בִּפְנֵי הָעוֹלָם הַבָּא. הַתְקֵן עַצְמְךָ בַפְּרוֹזְדוֹר, כְּדֵי שֶׁתִּכָּנֵס לַטְּרַקְלִין: ‏

We need a large explanation: We have a gangway and a palace.

Here is the text:

> והנה מה שהורונו חכמינו זכרונם לברכה הוא, שהאדם לא נברא אלא להתענג על ה' ולהנות מזיו שכינתו שזהו התענוג האמיתי והעידון הגדול מכל העידונים שיכולים להמצא. ומקום העידון הזה באמת הוא העולם הבא, כי הוא הנברא בהכנה המצטרכת לדבר הזה. אך הדרך כדי להגיע אל מחוז חפצנו זה, הוא זה העולם. והוא מה שאמרו זכרונם לברכה (אבות ד): **העולם הזה דומה לפרוזדור בפני העולם הבא**

The palace is the destination. Palace raise the idea of comfort and feeling of well being.

The gangway is a means, without gratifying aspect.

This is the proof of mesilat yesharim. The image of a gangway and a palace are image of means and destination. The destination is the purpose for which man is in live (is going in the gangway), the purpose is described as a placo of pleasure. So the purpose is pleasure. Where is it in Olam Haba. So what is the pleasure, the MY continues "שבתי בבית ה"

Comment: The mishna in Avot establishes that the route to "the Palace" is through this world. It does not prove that man in only created for the purpose of getting to "the Palace".

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok   So why people go to palace. for sport?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok The mesilat yesharim himself give the proof by the mishna.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok I hope that with the new edit it is clearly explained.

Answer (score 0):

1) In Derech HaShem, Ramchal founds this basic idea on the pasuk in Tehillim - "Tov HaShem laKol" - "G-d is good to all". He writes that the consequent of being good - is to do good. And thus HaShem created the world, to this end. That is a source in Tanach.

2) Chazal instituted Birkas HaIlanos with the expression that HaShem created beautiful creations "to give pleasure to people". So the concept is echoed in Chazal, albeit slightly qualified.

3) As a general rule to the principles of the Ramchal, R' Chaim Friedlander writes in his introduction to Daas T'vunos (I believe it was that sefer) that the principles of the Ramchal were learned bimsora - tradition passed through generations. This would include all applications and qualifications of Tanach and Chazal.

4) I may point out that this is easily derived from Chazal, in chain logic: {Step 1} Chazal teach us that the world was created for the purpose of Torah (Rashi B'reishis 1,1 s.v. from Midrash Rabba 1,1; also Rashi B'reishis 1, 31 from Tanchuma 1) and in fact it's Torah adherence that affords the world its sustainability (P'sachim 68b based on Yirmiya 33,25). {Step 2} The purpose of the Torah's mitzvos is to afford us merit (Final Mishna in Makkos). {Step 3} If the world was created for the Torah, and the Torah is there to benfit us, it logically is deduced that the purpose of creation was to benefit us. {Step 4} The greatest benefit, which Torah affords, is d'veikus to HaShem. (This, the Ramchal brings sources for himself.)

Comment: The Talmud's version is להתנאות not ליהנות, so 2 is pretty questionable.

Comment: Re 3: why had no Rishon mentioned them?

Comment: 1)  it is a source in tanach that God does good. how is it a source why He wants to do good?